# Where does one place share beans in the extension path in alfresco?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am trying to figure out where to place a share bean in the extension path. I have tried placing it in the following directories:

```
1) tomcat/shared/classes/
2) tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/
3) tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/web-extension
```

The bean has been declared in the **custom-slingshot-application-context.xml** along with some localized resources **(the .properties files <== They get picked up)**. Some additional info. It's a share side bean because I can drop the package into the src directory of the expanded war file in the IDE and run share and it'll work.

**Update**
This is the custom-slingshot-application-context.xml content:

```
<beans>
    <!-- Override WebScript Messages - add slingshot application messages -->
    <bean id="webscripts.resources" class="org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.ResourceBundleBootstrapComponent">
        <property name="resourceBundles">
            <list>
                <value>webscripts.messages.webscripts</value>
                <value>alfresco.web-extension.messages.common</value>
                <value>alfresco.web-extension.messages.slingshot</value>
                <value>alfresco.web-extension.messages.profPerson</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="webframework.factory.user.profPerson" class="com.test.ext.profUserFactory" parent="webframework.factory.base" />

</beans>
```

Comment: Are you making sure you're doing this in the Tomcat instance that is running Share? And have you ensured that that Tomcat is configured to use shared classpath?

Comment: Yes. Everything else extended works for the most part

Comment: `alfresco/web-extension/custom-slingshot-application-context.xml` under the tomcat `shared/classes/` directory should be all you need, provided your tomcat is configured to use that directory

Comment: Well whenever I put the bean directory in there, I still get a bean not found exception.

Comment: Try adding a syntax error to the file. If tomcat is seeing it, you'll get an exception at application startup. If not, then tomcat doesn't think that file is on the classpath!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're using Tomcat, but as @Gagravarr mentions unless you are using the Tomcat supplied by the Alfresco installers, then the `shared/classes` directory is not enabled out of the box.

In Tomcat6/7, you need to add the following line to your `conf/catalina.properties` file (or modify it if it is already defined)

```
shared.loader=${catalina.base}/shared/classes,${catalina.base}/shared/lib/*.jar
```

More information is available on the [Install Tomcat6](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Install_Tomcat6) wiki page.

Comment: All this is done and other elements of alfresco extended work with the exception of the bean I am trying to inject.

Comment: In that case I'd suggest you try @Gagravarr's above suggestion of introducing an error into the bean def. Without the actual XML content, it's difficult to come up with any other ideas, I'm afraid.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the xml. and I have also added an error into the file which doesn't change anything.

Comment: Thanks for the XML, however I am not sure what your `com.test.ext.profUserFactory` (is this a class of your own? By convention Java class names start with a capital letter, but this does not) class is supposed to do. Can you explain what the bean should do, and how you expect it to interact with other Spring beans (e.g. are you trying to override some default behaviour, if so then what?).

Comment: It's a bean that's meant to overide the constructUser and saveUser methods of the SlingshotUserFactory adapted from one of jpotts tutorials on how to add properties to a user.

Comment: I assume you mean this tutorial: http://ecmarchitect.com/archives/2012/02/27/1555. As Jeff mentions in the post the code is written for 3.4.d so may well be outdated, but one thought I had is did you configure your custom user factory in a `share-config-custom.xml` file or similar, as per Step 2 in the tutorial? It seems to me that your bean *is* being created, just it is not being *used*.

Comment: I had forgotten to do that, however it doesn't change the error. The code is still valid as it will work if the bean package (i.e. the directory path) is placed under the sources directory of the expanded war file and then the rebuilt war is deployed.

Comment: What error do you get? You did not mention any error previously.

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on the bean

Comment: I think you need to update the question with your other configuration files, and with the full stack trace of any exception.